# Java.lang.Object; cannot be cast to <hibernate entity>

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

So - I'm new to hiberate and Java in general. I've seen a couple threads in regards to this error, but none seem to fit my situation. I have a simple JPQL query as shown below that should returnthe function ID and name from the Function table/entity. This query is held within my FunctionRepository.java

```
@Query("SELECT func.functionId, func.functionName"
    + " FROM Function func")
List<Function> findItAll();



-----below is my FunctionService.java-------



public ArrayNode getAllFunctions() {
    ArrayNode json = null;
    try {
        List<Function> functions = (List<Function>) functionRepository.findItAll();
        json = crudEntitiesToJson(functions);
    } catch (CorruptDataException cdEx) {
        logger.error(cdEx.getMessage());
    }

    return json;
}
```

The "crudEntitiesToJson" method is the following;

```
private ArrayNode crudEntitiesToJson(Iterable<Function> entities) throws CorruptDataException {
    ArrayNode result = new ArrayNode(JsonNodeFactory.instance);
    for (Function entity : entities) {
        result.add(FunctiontoJson(entity));
    }
    return result;
}
```

And all of this is kicked off by my FunctionController.java

The project builds and runs fine, but when I try to hit the endpoint that kicks off that query I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.ge.starfish.entity.Function
```

I guess Im confused as to where I'm going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change for

```
@Query("SELECT func FROM Function func") 
List<Function> findItAll();
```

to retrieve all Functions instead of a array with the two attributes. it would also works:

```
@Query("FROM Function") 
List<Function> findItAll();
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks. I accepted this answer because it gave the fully modified bit of code, but all suggestions/responses are roughly the same.

Answer (score 1):

when selecting individual columns you don't get the Type (Function in your case) but an array of Objects, like: `Object[]`.

So try: `List<Object[]> findItAll();`

Or if fetching all columns is ok you can do it like Doleron's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are only selecting two fields of your entities:

```
func.functionId, func.functionName
```

That means, the query will return a list of object arrays, each with two elements, which you then try to cast to a list of Function objects. That doesn't work. Either add a mapping step in between or select the whole entity in your query.

Answer (score 0):

In JPQL, the SELECT clause defines what object types you want to retrieve from the database. Instead of querying for the fields, you should query for the whole object like this:

```
SELECT func FROM Function func
```

You can find more information and examples at [The Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html).